# How to use a PHP variable in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing PHP variable into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript)

I want to obtain a PHP variable, to use it in an `if`-condition in JavaScript.

I was trying to use it like this:

```
var phpLogin = <?php $_SESSION['login'] ?>;
```

But it's wrong in syntax terms. So, how can I use a PHP variable in JavaScript?

Comment: var phpLogin = <?php ECHO $_SESSION['login'] ?>; You forgot to echo varible. And check if key exists in $_SESSION before echo...

Comment: and possible more in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+pass+php+variable+to+javascript

Answer (score 3):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) and don't forget [`echo`](http://php.net/echo).

```
var phpLogin = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['login']) ?>;
```

Comment: No semi colon in the php code?

Comment: @Tim It's not necessary in this case.

Comment: OP also did not indicate that the returned data was desired to be in JSON format

Comment: You dont need one because it only contains a single statement and then closes out of php... but you can add it in if you like.

Comment: @Tim So? He has to use JSON, otherwise it'll only work if `$_SESSION['login']` is a number.

Comment: @Tim, that's the easiest way to escape string.

Comment: @Tim: Why would he not want it json encoded. IF hes going to be using it in js it saves him the trouble of trying to manually escape it himself.

Comment: My objective is to obtain this variable, to compare it with the content of a XML reply. So, the answer will be returned in XML.

Either way, it keeps me sending the following error:
`unexpected token '<'`. It happens on every solution presented by you.. Any clue about what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `echo`.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>
```

or just

```
<?=$_SESSION['login']?>
```

Comment: No semi colon terminating the PHP code in the 2nd example

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you forgot the `echo`:

```
var phpLogin = <?php echo $_SESSION['login'] ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`var phpLogin = "<?php =$_SESSION['login']; ?>";`

Comment: I tried, but, unfortunately, it returns it as a string.

Like: `"<?php =$_SESSION['login']; ?>"`, instead of a php variable.

Answer (score 1):

It may look like overkill, but for safety reasons you should use `json_encode` when echo'ing directly to PHP:

```
var phpLogin = <?=json_encode($_SESSION['login'])?>;
```

Or, in its longer form:

```
var phpLogin = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['login']); ?>;
```

Or, to also accept empty sessions:

```
var phpLogin = <?php echo @json_encode($_SESSION['login']); ?>;
```

This will simply output NULL when there's no login session.