# PHP variable to js variable in a WordPress theme

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, variables

I'm working with a wordpress theme, in the admin control panel I' ve added settings for the theme, here I can write some variables, like longitude and latitude for a map (works), and an email, that I need for a contact form, but this doesn' t work, I suppose that the problem is that I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/contactform.js"></script>
```

In fact if I do the same with the map, that now is

```
<div id="gmapp"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var lat;
                var lng;
                lat=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['latcord_text']);?>;
                lng=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['lngcord_text']);?>;
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

                var options = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };  

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmapp'), options);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                {
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                }
                );

            </script>
```

I tried to write so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/map.js"></script>
```

But I don't see the map, and variables aren't found.

So what should I do to get the variable from settings as I do with lat and lng? I should write the js code in the php as I did with map?

Comment: You seem to have a stray `<?php endif; ?>` from which i don't see the `if` part.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I' ve already corrected that

Comment: and I still have problem

Comment: Just to make sure, you are trying to move the second script tag into map.js, is that it?

Comment: yes, but if do that, I don't know why but the variables lat and lng don't take the php variables

Comment: They don't because your php engine does not process your .js files, they are passed as-is to your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move part of your code to the map.js file:

```
//map.js
var generateMap = function(lat,lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  var options = {
         zoom: 15,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };  

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmapp'), options);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
         position: latlng,
         map: map
       }
  );
}
```

and from your php, do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var lat=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['latcord_text']);?>;
  var lng=<?php echo($GLOBALS['desklab_theme_settings']['lngcord_text']);?>;
  generateMap(lat,lng);
</script>
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript) for other solutions regarding data passing from PHP to JS

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your map.js file to something like map.php so that the PHP engine parses it. Then your source will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/map.php"></script>
```

The contents will still be javascript with your PHP variables in place.

Comment: Now I try also your solution

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion. Instead of using `bloginfo('template_url')` you should start using `get_template_directory_uri()` as the previous is being deprecated.

PS. I do not have comment privilege unless I answer a post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget echo

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/contact-form/map.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't use echo, now I try

Comment: As you can see with developer tools of google, the js file is found and recognized, but doesn't take variable lat and lng

Comment: I see in the source:
http://wpthemes.mtxlab.us/test/wp-content/themes/DeskLab/contact-form/map.js