# Filling Backbone model with data from Laravel Cache

Tags: laravel, caching, backbone.js

Is it possible to fill Backbone model with data from laravel cache, and how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Even if i don't know laravel i think this is quite possible. You only need to "render" or "print out" your laravel cache into a JavaScript code block. Please also see [Passing PHP variable into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript/5310269#5310269) to see how you can pass values from php to JavaScript.

A good solution would be, if you can render out your laravel cache to json form and then pass this to the "model.set()" method of your Backbone model.

Comment: Thank you Cris. I am currenty working on that. It looks somethink like

`$brojtocnih['brojtocnih'] = Cache::get('brojtocnih');
 $brojnetocnih['brojnetocnih'] = Cache::get('brojnetocnih');
 $polje = array();
 array_push($polje, $brojtocnih, $brojnetocnih);
 return json_encode($polje);`

This returns collection of models.