# How to pass on php variables into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

please help me out in passing php variables into javascript variables. here s my code

```
<body>
<?php
$yr="2013";
$y=(int)$yr;
$mo="06";
$m=(int)$mo;
$da="04";
$d=(int)$da;
$hr="14";
$h=(int)$hr;
$mi="30";
$min=(int)$mi;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var current="Logout";        
var year=<?php echo $y;?>;
var month=<?php echo $m;?>;          
var day=<?php echo $d;?>;           
var hour=<?php echo $h;?>;          
var minute=<?php echo $min;?>; 
....
// displaying js variables....
....
<script>
</body>
```

out put is showing like 
NaN:NaN:NaN:NaN

Im New to programming please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: 1. How does your *display js variables* code look? 2. How does your final javascript work after compiling? (use *View Source*).

Comment: downvotes without any comment? How can new user of SO improve himself?

Comment: I hope this could help you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using? It should be noted that you're setting the variable `$m` to both month and minute, so it will have the value of the minute (`30`) when you assign it to the javascript variables

Comment: here is my display block 
    <td align="center" ><div class="numbers" id="dmin"></div></td> 
    <td align="center" ><div class="numbers" id="dsec"></div></td>
    .....
    document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML=dmin;
    document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML=dsec;

Comment: how you are displaying the numbers?

Comment: There's no such variables as `dmin` and `dsec`.

Comment: Im sorry i missed few statements

   
    var dmin=Math.floor(((tsecs%(60*60*1000*24))
                                        %(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    var dsec=Math.floor((((tsecs%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))
                                         %(60*1000))/1000*1);

where tsecs is total secs got throuh a formula and sure it holds an integer value.

Comment: code you posted first should just work. Please show us how how you display the variables. Please EDIT your question, if you want to add something in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<?php
$yr="2013";
$mo="06";
$da="04";
$hr="14";
$mi="30";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var current="Logout";        
var year=<?php echo $yr;?>;
var year=parseInt(year);  // try this
var month=parseInt(<?php echo $mo;?>); // or this         
var day=parseInt(<?php echo $da;?>);           
var hour=parseInt(<?php echo $hr;?>);          
var minute=parseInt(<?php echo $mi;?>); 
....
// displaying js variables....
....
<script>
</body
```

This should probably work

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

<s>To convert a `string` to `int` in PHP use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)</s>

But in your case you don't need to convert, you can just `echo` it to javascript.

```
$y = "2013";
$m = "06";

...

var year=<?php echo $y;?>;
var month=<?php echo $m;?>;
```

Will output

```
var year=2013;
var month=06;
```

Comment: Typecasting as an `int` works just as well as `intval`. [The only difference is that `intval` can convert to a different base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912599/is-there-any-particular-difference-between-intval-and-int). Casting as an `int` is also faster.