# Alternative ways of accessing PHP variables from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Javascript file with the code I need to run my PHP project, but since it's a `.js` file I can't embed the PHP variables (such paths, config variables etc...) using the the `<?php ... ?>` way.

So I thought that one possible way would be using `AJAX` requests or a `REST API`.

Then two questions came in my mind:

1. Could that lead to some performance issues? - I have to wait the server's response so I guess it's yes.
2. Which are the possible alternatives?

**Edit:**

The config variables are stored in a PHP class for easy access from the PHP code. If you can tell me a better way I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You could add all your variables as a json string or whatever to your HTML page and access them with JS.

Comment: Performance issues don't really come to mind if you're just grabbing a PHP variable, it's basically instantaneous (depending on the server speed...I guess my point was it's not like your querying the DB for a massive amount of data)

Comment: Right now I have a file that is included in the HTML head which acts as communication between the PHP and javascript, so I can have the heavy work in javascript in a separated `javascript.js`. However this is not the best as I'm mixing PHP, HTML and javascript in just few lines, so good question +1

Comment: Well, actually I'm doing just [what Chris suggests here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5310269/938236).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing PHP variable into JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript)

Comment: you can use a .php file: javascript doesn't really care about the mime type of external scripts...

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I was trying to avoid that, but I think that  the solutions posted in the answers below are the most practical, so I'll add some PHP lines to my JS files.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you cache that? Because that's the main idea in having the javascript as a separated file. I'd recommend to dig a bit more into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following in your `.htaccess` file, then your javascript files should be able to compile php inside js.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a php file that outputs javascript and use php code inside it:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); ?>
alert('<?php echo "test"; ?>');
```

Comment: And now the question is: Will that work with `RequireJS`? I don't know but i can try it (and I will tomorrow).

Comment: The browser will see it as a javascript file, so if including a js file from the server works with RequireJS this should too.

Comment: Yep, I know that, but I'm not sure how `RequireJS` configuration will do. I'll let you know if it works :)