# How to use a PHP var to on a javascript? (PHP code)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a cookie in JavaScript, but it isn't working. All the stuff works, but I'm having problems with JavaScript.

This is the code for my page. The mysql connection works well, I've just masked the entries.
http://pastebin.com/HfbZyVQZ

How do I can use the `'$playername'` with the `'setPlayer()'`?

Comment: You're not even calling the function, how would you like to use the $playername variable?

Comment: Try to keep the code on stackoverflow only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing PHP variable into JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310216/passing-php-variable-into-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can echo it

```
var playername = <?php echo $playername;?>
```

then you can use the var playername for your js.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

the better one is:

```
var anyVariable = <?php echo json_encode($anyVariable); ?>;
```

It will handle correctly strings, booleans, numbers and arrays.